# Add an extra <li> with each existing first letter on items value

Tags: php, javascript, jquery-plugins, alphabetical

In order to be able to use this awesome plugin: [Jquery iphone contacts](http://www.marcofolio.net/webdesign/the_iphone_contacts_app_with_css_and_jquery.html)

i need to update my existing markup  (normal list):

```
<div id="iphone-scrollcontainer">
   <ul id="iphone-search">
       <li><a href="#A" title="A">A</a></li>
        <li><a href="#B" title="B">B</a></li>
        <li><a href="#C" title="C">C</a></li>
        <li><a href="#D" title="D">D</a></li>
        <li><a href="#E" title="E">E</a></li>
        <!-- More characters here -->
    </ul>
   <ul id="iphone-scroll">
            <li><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amsterdam" title="Amsterdam"><strong>Amsterdam</strong>747,290</a></li>
             <li><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amsterdam" title="Barcelona"><strong>Barcelona</strong>747,290</a></li>
             <li><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amsterdam" title="Sevilla"><strong>Sevilla</strong>747,290</a></li>
             <li><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amsterdam" title="Cadiz"><strong>Cadiz</strong>747,290</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Into (Add Navigation indicators):

```
<div id="iphone-scrollcontainer">
   <ul id="iphone-search">
       <li><a href="#A" title="A">A</a></li>
        <li><a href="#B" title="B">B</a></li>
        <li><a href="#C" title="C">C</a></li>
        <li><a href="#D" title="D">D</a></li>
        <li><a href="#E" title="E">E</a></li>
        <!-- More characters here -->
    </ul>
   <ul id="iphone-scroll">
      <li>
        <div id="nav-indicator-fixed"></div>
        <a name="A"></a>
      <div class="nav-indicator" id="nav-a">A</div>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amsterdam" title="Amsterdam"><strong>Amsterdam</strong>747,290</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arnhem" title="Arnhem"><strong>Arnhem</strong>144,101</a></li>
            <!-- More info here -->
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a name="B"></a>
      <div class="nav-indicator" id="nav-b">B</div>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolsward" title="Bolsward"><strong>Bolsward</strong>9,607</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buren" title="Buren"><strong>Buren</strong>25,644</a></li>
            <!-- More info here -->
         </ul>   
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

So i have to

add:

```
 <div id="nav-indicator-fixed"></div>
            <a name="A"></a>
          <div class="nav-indicator" id="nav-a">A</div>
          <ul>
```

Before A items and

`</li></ul>` after A items, (and same with each existing first letter), am i right?

Now is when i don't know to do it in front end using jquery or if i can do it in the server using php

i generate my markup with a simple query: 'select name from citys order by name desc'

how and where would you do it?

(shouln't actually the plugin have the feature¿)

-EDIT-

php code was requested:

```
function nube_ingredientes($limit = 50){
    $query = "SELECT count(*) as num, nombre FROM ciudades WHERE GROUP BY nombre ORDER BY num DESC LIMIT $limit";

    $result = mysql_query($query);
        $html .= '<div class="content">';

            $html .=    '<ul>';
                while($taginfo = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
                     $numtags = $taginfo[0];
                     $tagname = $taginfo[1];
                     $tagurl = urlencode($tagname);
                     $tagsize = 9 + intval($numtags)*2;
                     $bla = 'get_items("'.str_replace(' ','-',$tagname).'")';
                     $tagname = str_replace('-', ' ', $tagname);
                      $html.= "<li><a href='#router' onclick='$bla' c='$numtags'>$tagname</a></li> "."\n";

                }
        $html .=    '</ul>
                  </div>';

        echo $html;
 }
```

Comment: Feel free to improve the title of the question

Comment: Please post your current PHP code to generate the list

Comment: For starters you always want to output the HTML as ready as possible; so you don't have to modify it afterwards which is heavy on the client especially mobile devices. So what is relevant here is the code in php that generates this list. You will have to change that code to output the new structure....

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet: Thanks, I've posted my answer based on your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested this, so consider it psuedo-code, however it should give you a good starting point.  The idea is to check the first letter of each row, and if it's different than the first letter of the previous row, emit the new HTML code.  It is always best to emit the HTML code as close to final as possible.  So this solution has no complicated changes required to the front end.

```
function nube_ingredientes($limit = 50){
$query = "SELECT count(*) as num, nombre FROM ciudades WHERE GROUP BY nombre ORDER BY num DESC LIMIT $limit";

$result = mysql_query($query);
    $html .= '<div class="content">';
        $html .=    '<ul>';
            while($taginfo = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
                 $numtags = $taginfo[0];
                 $tagname = $taginfo[1];
                 $tagurl = urlencode($tagname);
                 $tagsize = 9 + intval($numtags)*2;
                 $bla = 'get_items("'.str_replace(' ','-',$tagname).'")';
                 $tagname = str_replace('-', ' ', $tagname);
                 $thisChar = strtoupper(substr($tagname, 0, 1)); //Added by msigman
                 if($lastChar != $thisChar);//Added by msigman
                 {
                    $html .= "<li><div id='nav-indicator-fixed'></div>
                    <a name='$thisChar'></a>
                    <div class='nav-indicator' id='nav-$thisChar'>$thisChar</div>
                    <ul>"; //Added by msigman
                  }
                 $html.= "<li><a href='#router' onclick='$bla' c='$numtags'>$tagname</a></li> "."\n";
                 if($lastChar != $thisChar); //Added by msigman
                 {
                    $lastChar = $thisChar; //Added by msigman
                    $html .= "</li></ul>"; //Added by msigman
                 }
            }
    $html .=    '</ul></div>';
    echo $html;
```

}

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet How did it work out?  Were you able to resolve the issue?

Comment: unfortunatelly i haven't had time to test. but looking forward; will let you know! thanks again

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet Did you get it working?  If you found my post helpful, please mark it as Accepted.  If not, let me know how I can help further.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you might want to pass the basic data to the client without generating the markup in php, you can do it like this:

1. Ensure your server delivers the data in a compact form. As you said your data comes a SQL Query I assume you might easily dump it with `encode_json($results)` in PHP which will deliver something like this:

```js
// title, wiki-link, x-coord, y-coord
var data =
  [["Amsterdam", "Amsterdam", 747, 290],
   ["Barcelona", "Barcelona", 747, 290],
   ...
  ]
```

I've added the wiki-link just in case it's not the title ;)

Now using jQuery and [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org) you can generate your content with a few lines of code:

```
// group your data by the first letter of the title
var grouped = _.groupBy(data, function(row) { 
  // row[0] is the title
  return row[0].substring(0, 1)
})
// generate the header
var letters = _.keys(grouped)
var header = $('<ul>', { id: 'iphone-search' })
_.each(letters, function(letter) {
  $('<a>', { href: '#' + letter, title: letter }).html(letter).appendTo(header)
})

// the scroll body
var scrollBody = $('<ul>', { id: 'iphone-scroll' })
_.each(letters, function(letter) {
  var li = $('<li>')
  // create the navigational anchor
  $('<a>', { name: letter }).appendTo(li)

  // create the div to put the ul/li... on
  var div = $('<div>', { 
    'class': 'nav-indicator',
    'id': 'nav-' + letter.toLowerCase()
  }).appendTo(li)
  var ul = $('<ul>').appendTo(div)
  _.each(grouped[letter], function(group) {
    // now, for each element within the group
    // create the <li><a>...</a></li> content
    $('<li>').append(
      $('<a>', {
        title: group[0],
        href: 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/' + group[1] // the wiki-link
      }).append(
        $('<strong>').html(group[0])
      ).append(
        $('<span>').html(group[2] + ', ' + group[3])
      )
    ).appendTo(ul)
  })      
})

// now you can join them in the container
var container = 
  $('<div>', { id: 'iphone-scrollcontainer'}).append(header).append(scrollBody)
```

That should yield just the html you wanted ;)
The last part appears a little messy, but at least its the same style as all elements are only generated by jQuery.